# jQuery change not triggering after DIV has already been loaded, using CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

When a room_id is selected from the drop down, I use the JS helper to populate the security_deposit and room_rate inputs. The issue is that if I select a room_id, the room_rate_update jQuery change function stops working. However, when page loads and I don't select a room_id, I can type in the room_rate box and it's triggered, but not after I select a room_rate.

The one thing that I think may be causing this is when I select a room_id, the entire div containing the room_rate is updated. It was previously generated by the CakePHP form helper, however, I made sure that the div is replaced by the **exact** same name, class, id, etc... It's identical to the one that appears when the page loads

Here is the form in my view

```
echo $this->Form-create('Arrival');
echo $this->Form->input('room_id',array('options' => $room_numbers, 'label'=>'Room Number'));

?>
    <div id="room_rate_update">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('room_rate', array('label' => 'Room Rate (numbers only)'));
        ?>
    </div> 

   <div id = "security_deposit_update">
       <?php
           echo $this->Form->input('security_deposit',array('label' => 'Security Deposit (numbers only)'));
       ?>
   </div>
<?php

echo $this->Form->input('balance_upon_arrival',array('label' => 'Balance Due Upon Arrival'));
```

Here is the JS helper and jQuery function for the updates

```
//if someone changes the room_rate, this should update the deposit amount  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ArrivalRoomRate" ).change(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});


//populates the room rate when the room is selected
$this->Js->get('#ArrivalRoomId')->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'Arrival',
        'action'=>'getRoomRate'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#room_rate_update',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
);
```

Here is the view for the JS helper POST request

```
//room_rate_update.ctp

<div class="input text required">
    <label for="ArrivalRoomRate">Room Rate </label><input name="data[Arrival][room_rate]" maxlength="10" type="text" id="ArrivalRoomRate" required="required" value="<?php echo $room_rate; ?>">
</div>
```

So, as I stated. Prior to selecting a room_id, the "test" is triggered. After I select a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have another function, for instance :

```
function init ()
{
    $("#ArrivalRoomRate" ).change(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
}
```

After all content refreshed, then call it once. Otherwise, when all content refreshed, this event handler will be invalid for new content, coz it's partial rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a delegate(aka live) event handler like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body" ).on("change", "#ArrivalRoomRate", function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

If you have problem with `.on()` with jQuery version, then you can use `.live()` with old jQuery like following:

```
$("#ArrivalRoomRate").live("click", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: It's giving me troubles for .on(....). The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' "

Comment: @user2443591 that may be problem with jQuery version. for `on()` you need jQuery >= 1.7